# Lucene NumericRangeQuery and MemoryIndex

Tags: java, lucene

I am new to Lucene and am experimenting with some trivial use cases. I am unable to get the NumericRange dependent Unit test which asserts a successful range match to pass. What am I doing wrong.

```
public class MemoryIndexTest {

private static final String DATE_FIELD = "date";
MemoryIndex index = new MemoryIndex();


@Before
public void init() {
    index.addField(DATE_FIELD, index.keywordTokenStream(Arrays.asList(20141116)));
}

@Test
public void testRange(){
    Query query = NumericRangeQuery.newIntRange(DATE_FIELD, 20141115, 20141118, true, true);
    assertTrue(index.search(query) > 0);

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured this one out. From the documentation of [NumericRangeQuery](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_10_2/core/org/apache/lucene/search/NumericRangeQuery.html)

> A Query that matches numeric values within a specified range. To use this, you must first index the numeric values using **IntField, FloatField, LongField or DoubleField (expert: NumericTokenStream)**. If your terms are instead textual, you should use TermRangeQuery. NumericRangeFilter is the filter equivalent of this query.

The key here is for a MemoryIndex one has to use the NumericTokenStream. So modifying my test to index the field as

```
public class MemoryIndexTest {

    private static final String DATE_FIELD = "date";
    MemoryIndex index = new MemoryIndex();

    NumericTokenStream numericTokenStream = new NumericTokenStream();

    @Before
    public void init() {
        index.addField(DATE_FIELD, numericTokenStream.setIntValue(20141116));
    }

    @Test
    public void testRange() {
        Query query = NumericRangeQuery.newIntRange(DATE_FIELD, 20141115, 20141118, true, true);
        assertTrue(index.search(query) > 0);

    }
}
```

fixed the issue.